# IE is messing with my GET parameters

Tags: url, get, internet-explorer-9

One of my GET parameters was named &ordf, and today when I was expecting to test the rendering of a page in IE9 vs Chrome, I found instead that IE9 wouldn't even load the right data because it was converting &ordf to "ª"(no quotes) which is &ordf HTML special character.

Is there anything I can do to prevent IE from doing this? Chrome and Firefox don't have any problems with the URL and display it fine. The only fix I could think of was changing it from &ordf to something else, but I was hoping there was something easier or quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to escape the & in the url in the HTML file as &amp;